# Generating mouse events in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, usb, mouseevent, device-driver

I have an USB device that will send out some proprietary data and I have an algorithm that converts it to mouse coordinates, the question I have is how do I write a driver that reports to Mac OS X?

I have seen some references to `IOHIDPostEvent` but I cannot find detailed documentation on Apple's Developer Website. Is this the correct way? I am trying to write an user-space driver versus an in-kernel drive.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check a working but deprecated program here: http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2008051406323031

The new replacement for CGPostMouseEvent is CGEventCreateMouseEvent and you can read more about it here: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventCreateMouseEvent